# Win32Exception Access Denied

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, components, system

So im trying to run python code in C#. But when I'm trying to execute the command I get a error message:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access Denied'
```

Code:

```
private void run_cmd(string cmd, int args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = "C://Users//user//AppData//Local//Microsoft//WindowsApps//python.exe";
            start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

The error is happening at:

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
```

Comment: That error usually means there is a privileges disconnect. Why is 'python' installed under AppData - shouldn't it be under "C:\\Program files"? Is 'python' installed for all users? Is your app a service or something that requires to be run as Admin?

Comment: Is your app a UWP app?

Comment: Yes the app is a uwp app

Comment: I tried both running python from the windows store and python in my venv. But both gave me the same error. My app up to this point have been pretty basic so in my opinion I shouldn't need any privilege to run it.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Well yes and no, I was able to get a exe file up and running but unfortunately, I had no luck executing an external python script. So I decided to switch framework entirely. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0) is not supported in UWP apps. To run the exe file from your UWP app, I'd suggest you use [FullTrustProcessLauncher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-20348).

First, you need to copy the exe file and save it in the UWP app package, for example, the Assets folder. Then please go to the Manifest file and add the **runFullTrust restricted capability**.([App capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)). Next, add the reference of **Windows Desktop Extensions** for the UWP project. At last, you could call `await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();` to launch the exe file from your app.